# getting five random elements out of a java array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I've been working on this project for a few days now, I was able to complete most of it but I've been struggling on getting the five different items out of my array. I'm able to select the same item five times though.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
public class CardGuessingGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] myCards = new String[]{"two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"}; // Array for cards

        Random rand = new Random(); //random construction
        rand.nextInt(13); // Sets rand to 0-12 int
        //int randomNums = rand.nextInt(13); // sets randNums from 0-12
        int randomNums = rand.nextInt(myCards.length); //Randomizes "randomNums to the length of the array"
        String cardInHand = myCards[(int)randomNums];

        for (randomNums=0; randomNums < 5; randomNums++) {

            System.out.println(cardInHand);
        }

        System.out.print("Guess the card in my hand: "); // Prints to user asking for guess

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in); // gets user input
        String s = answer.nextLine(); //stores user input inside variable s

        if(s.equals(cardInHand)) {

            System.out.println("I do have that card in hand");
        } else {

            System.out.println("I do not have that card in hand!");
        }

        System.out.print("These were the cards I had in hand: ");
        System.out.println(cardInHand);
    }
}
```

and here's the output

```
run:
four
four
four
four
four
Guess the card in my hand: four
I do have that card in hand
These were the cards I had in hand: four
```

What I have right now works, but not correctly.

Comment: works but not correctly, so in other words it doesn't work :)

Comment: You only pick one `cardInHand`, and then use the `randomNums` in the `for` loop to print the single `cardInHand`.

Comment: Have you tried going over your work with your instructor or TA?  People here can probably show you working code, but you'd learn more by having a dialogue about what concepts you might be missing or misusing.

Comment: pjs, talked to my professor today and had him look over the code, he pointed out that I should have used a loop since I had 5 print statements (not really the major problem of this program, but fixed that part anyway.) tried pointing out what was going on with my program but he didn't really help, which is why i'm on stack.

Comment: If you want to guarantee different cards, consider using [Collections.shuffle](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-shuffle-java-examples/).  Then iterate through the shuffled list to get as many items as you need.  If you use random selection, you can get duplicates even if you correct your current bug of only calling `nextInt` a single time.  By the way, if you want a user to see your comment prefix their user name with "@", e.g., "@pjs".

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @NathanielSop As you can see, the SO community will often generate many fine answers.  It's great for you to select one as "the answer," but it's also often a good idea to wait a bit so you can see others that may roll in.

Comment: @pjs I realize that now, thanks for your help! as well as everyone else for posting great answers! will keep that in mind the next time I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you have a misconception about what rand.nextInt(13) does. Here you created your object of random correctly however the second line, you think  its setting rand to 0-12, when its actually just calling a method to return a random integer from 0-12 and doing absolutely nothing with that.

   ```
   Random rand = new Random(); //random construction
   rand.nextInt(13); // Sets rand to 0-12 int
   ```
2. a. You set the variable randomNums to some random value, I'm not sure why, when you just reset it to zero in the for loop before any possible usage.

   b. Your general method of storing cards is incorrect as you should to make a new ArrayList that will store the 5 cards, but in reality, you just generated one single card and printed it 5 times

   ```
   int randomNums = rand.nextInt(myCards.length);
   String cardInHand = myCards[(int)randomNums];
   for (randomNums=0; randomNums < 5; randomNums++) {
       System.out.println(cardInHand);
   }
   ```

This is what a cleaner, more logical version of your code should look like.

```
String[] myCards = {"two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
Random rand = new Random();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int cardIndex = rand.nextInt(myCards.length);
ArrayList<String> playerHand = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    while (playerHand.contains(myCards[cardIndex]))
        cardIndex = rand.nextInt(myCards.length);
    playerHand.add(myCards[cardIndex]);
}
System.out.print("Guess the card in my hand: ");
if(playerHand.contains(scan.nextLine()))
    System.out.println("I do have that card in hand");
else
    System.out.println("I do not have that card in hand!");
System.out.print("These were the cards I had in hand: ");
System.out.println(playerHand);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote new code to develop your ambiguity when reading the source code. So i added comment to some lines to understand clearly.

```
public class CardGuessingGame  {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //list of cards
        List<String> myCards = Arrays.asList("two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace");
        //shuffle cards
        Collections.shuffle(myCards);

        //get first 5 elements from shuffled list
        HashSet<String> myHand = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            myHand.add(myCards.get(i));
            System.out.println(myCards.get(i));
        }

        System.out.print("Guess the card in my hand: "); // Prints to user asking for guess

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in); // gets user input
        String s = answer.nextLine(); //stores user input inside variable s

        //if set contains , you found the card
        if (myHand.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println("I have that card in my hand");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I do not have that card in hand!");
        }

        System.out.print("These are the cards which is in my hand: ");
        //write all cards in my hand with sepearete comma
        System.out.println(String.join(",", myHand));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works and only takes unique cards. First you should get a gasp which of your variables are arrays and which are not.

A call to `rand.nextInt(13);` doesn't set the Random instance to produce random numbers between 1 and 13 but actually generates one.

And your random number generation should be put inside the loop. cards in hand needs to contain multiple values therefore an array should be used.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardGuessingGame {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] myCards = new String[] { "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
                "jack", "queen", "king", "ace" }; // Array for cards

        //Random rand = new Random(); // random construction
        //rand.nextInt(13); // Sets rand to 0-12 int
        // int randomNums = rand.nextInt(13); // sets randNums from 0-12

        String[] cardsInHand = new String[5];

        List<String> cards = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(myCards));
        Collections.shuffle(cards);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //This will not give you unique cards!
            //int randomNums = rand.nextInt(myCards.length); // Randomizes "randomNums to the length of the array"
            cardsInHand[i] = cards.remove(0);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cardsInHand));

        System.out.print("Guess the card in my hand: "); // Prints to user asking for guess

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in); // gets user input
        String s = answer.nextLine(); // stores user input inside variable s


        //Some kind of contains method. You can traverse the array use a list or do however you like
        Arrays.sort(cardsInHand);

        if (Arrays.binarySearch(cardsInHand,s) >= 0) {

            System.out.println("I do have that card in hand");
        } else {

            System.out.println("I do not have that card in hand!");
        }

        //Close the stream
        answer.close();

        System.out.print("These were the cards I had in hand: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cardsInHand));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I will try to explain where you went wrong, and give you and example of working code.

I am assuming that you are supposed to use arrays only for this, and that you are not to repeat numbers.

**First**

You are setting `cardInHand` to `myCards[(int)randomNums]`. Then you loop `5` times and print `cardInHand` to the console. You never set the card to anything else.

**Second**

Even if you were to set `cardInHand` to something else, you have now lost the previous card information. What you are missing is another array to save the card information. This can be done by using a loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cardInHand = myCards[rand.nextInt(myCards.length)];
    cardsInHand[i] = cardInHand;
}
```

This achieves saving the card to an array for later use.

Here is working code that solves your issue.

```
String[] myCards = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
Random rand = new Random();
String[] cardsInHand = new String[5];
int[] usedNums = new int[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    usedNums[i] = -1;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int randNum = rand.nextInt(myCards.length);
    boolean contains = false;
    do
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(usedNums[j] != randNum)
            {
                contains = false;
                continue;
            }
            contains = true;
            randNum = rand.nextInt(myCards.length);
        }
    }
    while(contains);
    cardsInHand[i] = myCards[randNum];
    usedNums[i] = randNum;
}

Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = answer.nextLine();

boolean hasCard = false;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(cardsInHand[i].equals(s)
    {
        hasCard = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(hasCard)
{
    System.out.println("Has card");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not has card");
}

System.out.println("Cards in hand:");
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    System.out.println(cardsInHand[i]);
}
```

If you can use overlapping numbers, then remove references to `usedNums`, and the `do..while` loop.